# Qliksense how works webapp?

Tags: web-applications, qliksense

Anybody knows how do I use **Webapp** in QlikSense? **mashup** is equal Webapp? I ve looking for this solution but I did not found it. What is the best mode to resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following applies to your questions:

- Mashup is using the Capabilies APIs.
- Web App is using the Engine APIs - you create everything custom and let the Qlik engine handle the data.

If you need examples look at my github account under Qlik Integration.